# Magento Import Products CSV

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am using **magento community 1.9.1 version** and Trying to **import products through CSV**. in csv i have mention **all fields** and **trying to create custom option** but after completion of import product custom option not created.so please any body can give me suggestion **how to create custom option while importing products through csv**.

Comment: Using csv file you can only insert/update values in magento. You should first manually create all custom options then try to import the product csv. It should work.

Comment: Use see this [link](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-exportimport-data-in-csv-files.html). complete tutorial.